# how i create chat Application without firebase, socket.io , pubnub?

Tags: java, android

In my program I want users can send private messages to each other. Like Instagram Direct.

First, I tried to go through Firebase, but my country, Iran, was banned through Google.

Then I decided to try punnub, but it's only possible to create a group chat, which works on Android 4.2.2 and above.

Then I tried the socket.io , but I could not set it up on my server.

There is no other way in my mind.

please help me to I can solve this problem.

Comment: pubnub supports group and one to one take both

Comment: @akhilesh-patil its works on Android 4.2.2 and upper :(.

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Chat Engine

Quickblox is definitely a great quick trip to chat and likely exactly what you are looking for (since you said "not PubNub" and other similar services).

But PubNub is also working on [Chat Engine](https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine) which provides all the chat features you want (on top of PubNub's service) and allows for greater customization. It's a new framework and there will be many more changes/improvements coming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quickblox to implement Chat into your Android App. Its Free

https://quickblox.com/ - This is their Site Also i am attaching Android Documentation which you can try into your App

https://quickblox.com/developers/Android